# Symfony generates a lot of queries during form handleRequest, each for every collection item

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have Entity, let's call it "Group" that has a collection of Items.
Every item has relation to SubItem. So summarizing, it looks like:

```
Group {
  Items: Collection [
    Item { SubItem },
    Item { SubItem },
    ...
    Item { SubItem },
  ]
}
```

I have created a form where I can create/edit such group by **CollectionType**, you can give it name and add/remove Item(s). I can load such form with just one query, but when I send the form, symfony fires one query per SubItem in Item in collection, event if SubItems are all the same, the queries looks like:

```
 SELECT 
   ... (all fields list)
 FROM 
   subItem s0_ 
 WHERE 
   s0_.id IN (?)
```

So giving an example:

[image: Example form data]

It will produce 4 of those queries:

```
SELECT ... FROM subItem s0_ WHERE s0_.id IN ('SubItemA.id')
SELECT ... FROM subItem s0_ WHERE s0_.id IN ('SubItemB.id')
SELECT ... FROM subItem s0_ WHERE s0_.id IN ('SubItemB.id')
SELECT ... FROM subItem s0_ WHERE s0_.id IN ('SubItemB.id')
```

I don't use **WHERE IN()** in any of my DQL. Do you have any Idea where it comes form or how to track those down?

**EDIT:** I found something out. SubItem is EntityType, and when I set 'query_builder' with order by DESC/ASC, it does appear in those queries. But still I don't know why and where **WHERE id IN()** comes from. And those queries are only about Subitems sent in form. Whole list that populates EntityType field is longer.

**Edit 2:** Those queries seems to be just queries that check if chosen entity exists. I started using ChoiceType instead with model transformer, I feed my form witch $id => $entity array so I can transform back from id to entity, and I need to grab entities list only once, not once per EntityType field as symfony does.

Comment: Could you show us your formType/FormBuilder ?

Comment: @po_taka, I have replaced EntityType with ChoiceType, and all is ok now. Those queries was most likely checks if chosen id exists in entity table, and it was done for each field separately.